# I am making a multithreaded application to process an image yet the sequential version is faster, why?

Tags: java, multithreading, bufferedimage

I am having static BufferedImage in the threads and letting each thread modify some sections of the image. The processing is extremely independent as each pixel is done separately, yet the sequential version is faster how could I fix that?

edit 1: here how the code looks like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    long startime, endtime;
    long Time;
    startime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //also tried to use nano

    WorkingThread T1 = new WorkingThread("input.jpg");
    WorkingThread T2 = new WorkingThread();
    WorkingThread T3 = new WorkingThread();
    WorkingThread T4 = new WorkingThread();

    T1.start();
    T2.start();
    T3.start();
    T4.start();

    T1.join();
    T2.join();
    T3.join();
    T4.join();

    endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Time = endtime - startime;
    System.out.println("The time consumed in miliseconds is  " + Time);
}

public class WorkingThread extends Thread {

  public static BufferedImage img;
  public static int p;
  public int nb;
  public static int width, height;

  public WorkingThread(String file) throws IOException {
    File f = new File(file);
    img = ImageIO.read(f);
    width = img.getWidth();
    height = img.getHeight();
    p = 1;
    nb = 0;
}

  public WorkingThread() {
    nb = p;
    p++;
}

  public void run() {

    int start=nb*height/p;
    int end = (nb + 1) * height/p;
    //the image will be split according to y axis in this case
    for(y=start; y < end ; y++) {
       for(x =0; x<width; x++) {
            pixel = img.getRGB(x, y);
            //processing
            img.setRGB(x, y, pixel);
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Might just have a small image where the overhead of threading is not worth it.

Comment: This is going to be pretty hard to talk about without seeing any code. Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: How are you measuring the results? Probably your benchmark is not done right, or maybe your current design in fact won't have a better performance than the sequential solution, but we cannot know since we can't see the code.

Comment: Multithreading adds some overhead to any processes, so if your image is not that big or the generation is not very time consuming, then multiple threads might be slower than one single thread.

Comment: I tried to use larger image but in fact the difference increased, I will edit and add the code right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have already pointed out, the flaw in your benchmark is that *the overhead of the thread setup and teardown is larger than the time it actually takes to execute your code sequentially*.

By inserting some silly code that takes a lot of time, like the below:

```
//processing
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    pixel = ((~pixel ^ pixel) | pixel) & pixel;
}
```

...inside the `for` `x`/`y` loop and increasing the max value of `i`, you'll see that eventually the multithreaded version will be faster than the sequential one.

PS: I used an image that is roughly 2500 x 3300 pixels.